I want to know how to get the public module in GEE
var Get_S_Series = require('users/Conala/QuickModel:Algorithms/GetSentinelImage');

I hope to get the "GetSentinelImage" module,
however, I have not found it anywhere
Where can I get it?

If you can't get it, it is not public/exists anymore.
